# objective-c mac os NSImageView on NSScrollView. When scrolled NSScrollView image break or incorrect image draw

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

When scrolled NSScrollView image break or incorrect image draw.
Any ideas ?

[image: before]

[image: after]

SSCanvasView : NSScrollView - when add image on canvasview. SSCanvasView : NSViewController.
I'm use xib and Constraints. I dont see incorrect code, but i think problem ib property xib.

```
- (void) addCanvasView:(SSCanvasObject*)canvasObject
{

    SSCanvasImageView *canvasImageView = [[SSCanvasImageView alloc]init];
    [canvasImageView setCanvasObject:canvasObject];
    [canvasImageView setAcceptsTouchEvents:false];

    CGPoint lastPoint = CGPointMake(0, 0);
    [self addSubview:canvasImageView];
    CGRect canvasImageViewRect = canvasImageView.frame;
    canvasImageView.frame = canvasImageViewRect;

    [self.canvasImages addObject:canvasImageView];
    [self.canvasImageHashMap setObject:canvasImageView forKey:canvasObject.key];
}

- (void) drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect
{


    [super drawRect:dirtyRect];
    if (_isEnabledHightlight) {
        [[NSColor blueColor]set];
    } else {
        [[NSColor blackColor]set];
    }

    NSFrameRect([self bounds]);
}
```

Comment: Here's one idea: show some code so we can help you better. It's really hard to guess what's going on here.

Comment: i find error. For correct addSubView on NSScrollView need add on DocumentView.  [self.documentView addSubview:canvasImageView];

Comment: Awesome. Answer your own question. Then you can accept the answer. You could add it to the ScrollView directly in some cases but it's asking for trouble. Best to add to the document view or even set it as the document view. ( depends on goals)